# How to to addClass() to the active link of two different navs based on scroll position in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have two navs, both with the class of `.fixed-nav` and would like to add a class to the active link of each nav (i.e. `.menu__item--current` for the `#main-nav` and `.is-selected` for the `#cd-vertical-nav`), based on scroll position (snippet below).

This part seems to be wrong:

```
updateMainNavigation(), updateVerticalNavigation();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateMainNavigation(), updateVerticalNavigation();
});
```

My first try doesn't work:

```
updateMainNavigation();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateMainNavigation();
});

updateVerticalNavigation()
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    updateVerticalNavigation();
});
```

[Here is the snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/VitoLattarulo/epmv3jgr/2/)

Comment: As you can see in the snippet, every time the new section hits the vertical breakpoint, the corresponding bullet on the right nav does not get any specific style.

Comment: what we can mostly see is a huge wall of text and code. are you sure this is the minimal code necessary to understand the question?

Comment: I agree and I am sorry. I am new here and don't know yet how to do things the proper way. Would there be a way to show only the snippet and the normal text, without all the code?

Comment: yeah, you can edit your own question and remove unnecessary code or text

Comment: Ok, I see. No need for css and stuff. Would the snippet still work?

Comment: I rarely use snippets, but you can edit your question as many times as you wish, so give it a try

Comment: I will just sign up to JsFiddle and just put the link in the question ;)

Comment: good edit. this is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function to listen for scrolling.  Calculate which div you are currently at and then select that element and change its css.  You can tweak the `number` calculation if you want it to change earlier.  I would add a class to your `vertical-navs`.  In this case, `class="vert-nav"`.

```
function changeDots(distanceFromTop) {
    var number = Math.ceil(distanceFromTop / 400);

    $('.cd-dot').css({background: "#fff"});
    $('.is-selected').removeClass("is-selected");
    if (distanceFromTop === 0) { 
        $($('.cd-dot')[0]).css({background: "#000"});
        $($('.vert-nav')[0]).addClass("is-selected");
    } else  {
        $($('.cd-dot')[number - 1]).css({background: "#000"})
        $($('.vert-nav')[number - 1]).addClass("is-selected");
    }       
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    changeDots(distanceFromTop);
});
```

Here's an example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/napoleon/pen/oxNLeR)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My main issue was actually how to apply your code to two different navs, with a specific class for each nav, so that the bullet will change as well as the border bottom of the top nav.

Comment: In that case you'd just throw that element in as well and change its css.  I'll alter the code in the answer.

Comment: Let me know if that's not what you're looking for. I wasn't positive whether you mean the `vertical-nav`s or the navbar that's fixed at the top of the window.  I went with the `vertical-nav` idea.  If you wanted something else targeted, just switch it out in the javascript.  Once they have `class` `is-selected`, you can use css to change the bottom of the border.  I also updated the CodePen.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again! This looks great! I would actually love to add the `is-selected` class to both `nav`s, so that the bullet becomes black AND the `border-bottom` changes. This was my main issue, how to make the code work to both of the `nav`s at the same time. Comma separated selectors did not work and I have no clue how to do it.